# MixPanel - Create User Profiles for already signed up users

Tags: analytics, user-profile, mixpanel

Hi Im implementing mixpanel for an existing web app with existing signed up users.
The normal flow for new users is that I call alias followed by mixpanel.people.set() on sign up to create user profiles. On Login I would only call identify() to link events to an already existing profile.

The problem happens with already pre-mixpanel signed up users. They won’t sign up so mixpanel.people.set() won’t be called and hence all existing signed up users pre-mixpanel won’t have a user profile. The only way I can think of is to check upon login if the user has a user profile in mixpanel and if not call mixpanel.people.set(). Is there a way to check if a user already has a user profile in mixpanel? Alternatively is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? If so, how? We have the same issue.

Comment: @AdamatAvidnote Yes, I call mixpanel.people.set_once() upon login, if the user isn't registered in mixpaned yet they get a new profile, otherwise the call gets ignored.
https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.people.set_once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the method that solves this:
mixpanel.people.set_once - set properties if they don't exist

https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/javascript-full-api-reference#mixpanel.people.set_once